# Обновление записи в таблицe sqlite в java

Tags: java, sqlite

Операция выполняется без ошибок, но обновление не происходит

```
 try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
connection.prepareStatement("update Auto set 
Model=?,Data_vipuska=?,Color=?,Probeg=?,Price=? where id_auto=?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine(); //модель
        String s1 = sc.nextLine(); //дата выпуска
        String s2 = sc.nextLine(); //цвет
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            int s3 = sc.nextInt();// пробег
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int s4 = sc.nextInt(); // цена
                if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    int s5 = sc.nextInt();// id
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, s);
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, s1);
                    preparedStatement.setString(3, s2);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(4, s3);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(5, s4);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(5, s5);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    preparedStatement.close();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели неправильный id");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Вы ввели неправильную цену");
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели неправильный пробег");

        }
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Вы совершили ошибку, попробуйте еще раз");

    }
    System.out.println("Данные изменены");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Чему равны `s1`, `s2`, `s3` и т.д.? Если убрать сканнер и захардкодить их запрос сработает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мало информации для ответа, но скорее всего здесь ошибка:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(5, s4);
preparedStatement.setInt(5, s5);
```

скорее всего имелось ввиду:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(6, s5);
```

из-за неправильного `id` обновление не выполняется.